# What does this error message mean, it's caused by the rokonandroid game engine

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures, rokon

I'm having problems with an app engine now that I have my whole game set up, it kind of sucks.
What's this error message mean?  I really don't understand what the problem is.  Is the problem with one of my sprites that is causing the game engine to get mad?

```
12-13 12:48:15.389: ERROR/Rokon(1776):   addToActive(1505553220)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776): java.lang.Exception:   addToActive(1505553220)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Debug.error(Debug.java:71)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.TextureManager.addToActive(TextureManager.java:54)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Texture.onLoadTexture(Texture.java:228)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.checkTextureValid(GLHelper.java:201)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.bindTexture(GLHelper.java:189)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.drawNormal(GLHelper.java:366)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.DrawableObject.onDrawNormal(DrawableObject.java:382)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.DrawableObject.onDraw(DrawableObject.java:360)
12-13 12:48:15.389: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Layer.onDraw(Layer.java:138)
12-13 12:48:15.397: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Scene.onDraw(Scene.java:934)
12-13 12:48:15.397: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.RokonRenderer.onDrawFrame(RokonRenderer.java:40)
12-13 12:48:15.397: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1112)
12-13 12:48:15.397: WARN/System.err(1776):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:946)
```

Any input would be useful, thank you!

Comment: The great thing about repeatable exceptions is you can observe the triggering input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at the source code, it would appear that Rokon just throws a random exception so it's kinda tricky to trace where the issue is really coming from.

I think your best bet would to be switching over to using the Java source code for the app and debugging it from there.

The most likely culprit is in 
[TextureManager.java](https://github.com/csaunders/rokon/blob/master/src/com/stickycoding/rokon/TextureManager.java)

Try to figure out what is the state of that texture you are trying to load/reload and it may help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try to figure out what is the state of that texture you are trying to load/reload and it may help you."
Relatively new programmer here, so I apologize if this seems like a relatively obvious comment. Also, I don't know if you were able to tell at all, but can you tell if it's my texture that is causing an issue for the game engine?

Comment: From what I've done with the Rokon game engine, it's best to include the source code in your project so you can run the application with the debugger attached.  That way you can inspect the code via eclipse and see what is going on under the covers when things decide to crash.  Also, whats great about running it with the debugger attached is eclipse will (most likely) automatically stop at the line of code that is causing your application to crash. It's hard to tell by looking at it though since he is just throwing a plain exception with little to no details contained in the message.