# Why do some of my Textures cause this error?

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es

I've been making a game using the rokonandroid game engine, but I randomly get an error that causes the layout to just stay as it is, and never update.

The following error occurs:

12-13 15:05:17.876: ERROR/Rokon(2798):   addToActive(229433297)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798): java.lang.Exception:   addToActive(229433297)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Debug.error(Debug.java:71)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.TextureManager.addToActive(TextureManager.java:54)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Texture.onLoadTexture(Texture.java:228)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.checkTextureValid(GLHelper.java:201)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.bindTexture(GLHelper.java:189)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLHelper.drawNormal(GLHelper.java:366)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.DrawableObject.onDrawNormal(DrawableObject.java:382)
12-13 15:05:17.876: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.DrawableObject.onDraw(DrawableObject.java:360)
12-13 15:05:17.884: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Layer.onDraw(Layer.java:138)
12-13 15:05:17.884: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.Scene.onDraw(Scene.java:934)
12-13 15:05:17.884: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.RokonRenderer.onDrawFrame(RokonRenderer.java:40)
12-13 15:05:17.884: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1112)
12-13 15:05:17.884: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.stickycoding.rokon.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:946)

What causes this error?  Anybody know of how to fix this error?  And is it possible that my textures are causing this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this error message mean, it's caused by the rokonandroid game engine.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433406/what-does-this-error-message-mean-its-caused-by-the-rokonandroid-game-engine)

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice.  If you don't receive a good answer, add additional details or create a bounty.  Additionally, you might have better luck in the game dev stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your textures need to have the size with the power of 2, like 64px x 64px, 128x128, 256... etc?

Comment: No.  One of the default sprites that comes with the engine is 35x50.